# How can I remove a randomly chosen element from a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to do an assignment for a class where I use the remove method of a String Bag class to return all the elements of a linked list, one at a time, then delete that element from the list. I have a start, but I can't figure out exactly how to do it. Can anyone help?

```
 public String remove()
  {
      Random rand = new Random();
      int randNum = rand.nextInt(numItems);
      //generate random number
      int count = 0;
      String get;
      currNode = firstNode;
      //temporary node to get String from

      while(count < randNum)
      {
          currNode = currNode.getLink();  
          count++;
      }
      //randomly select node to get String from
      get = currNode.getInfo();

      numItems--;
      if(numItems == 0)
      {
          firstNode = null;
      }
      //decrement the number of items in the bag and make the first node
      //null when it reaches 0
      return get;

  }
```

edit: Here is the application level:

```
public class StringBagTest 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {          
    LLStringBag bag = new LLStringBag();
    bag.insert("Hat");
    bag.insert("Shirt");
    bag.insert("Pants");
    bag.insert("Shoes");
    //insert 4 strings into the list
    while(!bag.isEmpty())
    {
    System.out.println(bag.remove());
    }
    //randomly removes all contents of list
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to remove an link(itme) by key or what? also you speak about simple linked list or double linked list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove randomly chosen element by index then it looks something like this:

```
public void removeRandomElement() {
        int index = new Random().nextInt(size);
        Node current = head;
        Node prev = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            prev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        prev.next = current.next;
        current.next = null;
        size--;
    }
```

For singly linked list, where `size` is current size of the list, `head` — head node.

In other terms, you're doing something like this on the selected element :
[image: illustrated removal of element in linked list]

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for. Can you eleborate on the "prev.next = current.next andcurrent.next = null" lines? Do you mean I needto set the links of those nodes?

Comment: Yes. We do somthing like [this](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2ebcnq1.jpg)(I'm not a good painter)

Comment: I think it needs a special case for when the random index is the head? (I might be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all elements of a linked list, you can use the built in clear() method.

If you don't want to use that method, you can just set the head node to null. The garbage collector will take care of the rest.

If you want a remove method that removes one thing at a time and you don't care what it removes, I suggest just removing the first element you find. If it's in a linked list, you can just assign a temp node to the head node, reassign the head node to the next node, and return the temp node.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: 
[link](http://%20%09%20Take%20a%20look%20at%20this%20link:%20[link%20here][1]%20[1]:%20stackoverflow.com/questions/10042/%E2%80%A6%20If%20if%20not%20enought%20let%20me%20know.%20%E2%80%93%20%20crAlex%20just%20now)

Also a full example:(**making your own Links and Lists**)

*(The example below is a Linked list which have(links) it's link is a point for example A(50,3). You can transform it to be whatever you want...)*

The Link

```
public class DoublePoint {

public double X;
public double Y;
public int LinkKey=0;
public DoublePoint nextLink; //keeps the nextLink

//Constructor
public DoublePoint(double Xpos,double Ypos,int key){
    X=Xpos;
    Y=Ypos;
    LinkKey=key;
}



public void printLinkKey(){
    System.out.println(LinkKey);
}


 //Return Link key

public String returnLinkKey(){

    return ""+LinkKey;
}



 public void changeContent(double x,double y){
      X=x;
    Y=y;

  }

public void ChangeLinkKey(int key){
    LinkKey=key;

}

  }
```

The List:

```
public class ListDoublePoints {

 public DoublePoint first;
 public int key; 
 public int totalLinks=0; 

public ListDoublePoints(){
    first=null;
    key=0;
}


//Insert


public void insertLink(double x,double y){
   DoublePoint newLink = new DoublePoint(x,y,key);
   newLink.nextLink=first;
   first=newLink;
   key++;
   totalLinks++;
}



//Find


public DoublePoint findLinkAt(int key){
    DoublePoint current=first;

 while(current.LinkKey!=key){ 
     if(current.nextLink==null)
         return null;
     else
        current=current.nextLink;

 }
 return current;

}


//Delete using Link key (similar with remove(int position) with ready java lists)


public String deleteLinkAt(int linkKey){

    DoublePoint current =first;
    DoublePoint previous=first;

    while(current.LinkKey !=linkKey){
        if(current.nextLink == null ){
            return "boom";}
        else
            previous=current;
            current=current.nextLink;
    }

    if(current==first)
        first=first.nextLink;
    else
        previous.nextLink=current.nextLink;

    --totalLinks;

    return "ok";
}


//Return


public int  LinksNumber(){
     return totalLinks;
}



//Print


public void displayList(){
   DoublePoint current=first;
  while(current!=null){
     current.displayLink();
     current=current.nextLink;
   }

}


 public void displayTheNumberOfLinks(){
    System.out.println(totalLinks);
  }

}
```

*Let me know if you want something like this above or

just to work with the java ready lists..*

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean something like this???

## Code

```
 private LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();

    private void fillList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add("Hello " + i);
        }
    }

    private void removeAllRandomly() {

        Random random = new Random();

        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            int randomPosition = random.nextInt(list.size());
            String s = list.remove(randomPosition);
            System.out.println(String.format("Item on position: %s (%s) was removed", randomPosition, s));
        }

    }
```

---

## Result

```
Item on position: 9 (Hello 9) was removed
Item on position: 1 (Hello 1) was removed
Item on position: 1 (Hello 2) was removed
Item on position: 2 (Hello 4) was removed
Item on position: 5 (Hello 8) was removed
Item on position: 0 (Hello 0) was removed
Item on position: 3 (Hello 7) was removed
Item on position: 1 (Hello 5) was removed
Item on position: 1 (Hello 6) was removed
Item on position: 0 (Hello 3) was removed
```